# Access to element with the same names in a list

Tags: r

I have a list with elements that have the same name "element".

```
li <- list(element=list(id=1, name="x"), element=list(id=2, name="y"))
```

And I want to get the "name" of the element with an "id" equals to X.

Firstly i thought that I could do it with :

```
 li[[which(li$element$id == 1)]]$name
```

But the problem is that `li$element` refers to the first element "element" of the list ...

```
> li$element
$id
[1] 1

$name
[1] "x"
```

So if I look for an id different from the id of the first element of my list it returns "interger(0)"

```
> which(li$element$id == 2)
integer(0)
```

Actually I do like this :

```
for (element in li) {
    if(element$id == 2) {
        name <- element$name
    }
}
```

But I wonder if there is a better way to do it, or if I missed something with the basic list notions (acces to elements ...).

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to find the name when all names are identical?

Comment: Oh sorry my example is confusing, by "find the name" I mean the element "name"  of an element which is : "li$element$name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
li[sapply(li, function(x) x["id"]==2)][[1]][["name"]]
#[1] "y"
```